# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): action.assetList is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I don't know why it is giving me this error, I am quite new at this
This is what my 2 files throwing the error looks like

This is my crypto.js file

```js
const crypto = (state = cryptoDefault, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_ASSET_LIST:
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      return [
        ...action.assetList,
      ];
    case UPDATE_CRYPTO_ASSET:
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      return {
        ...action.assetData,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default crypto;
```

This is my index.js file

```js
const updateApiRenderList = () => (dispatch, getState) => fetchApiCryptoList(
  {
    url: null,
    currency: getState().currencyFilter,
  },
)
  .then((result) => {
    dispatch(updateAssetList(result));
  }).catch((error) => {
    throw (error);
  });

export {
  updateAssetList, updateCryptoAsset,
  nextPage, prevPage, updatePage,
  fetchApiAssets, fetchApiSuccess, fetchApiFailure,
  updateApiRenderList,
  filterUpdate,
  currencyUpdate,
  getCurrenCurrency,
};
```

Comment: it means that you `action.assetList` is not an array . Add a console.log and check

Comment: @Shyam to which of them please, I am quite a noob at this thing lol
I am following a tutorial

Comment: add console.log(action.assetList) below this `case UPDATE_ASSET_LIST:`  in your crypto.js file

Comment: @Shyam  it did not work, thanks for your help tho

Comment: :-) mate it will not work because i haven't told you the solution yet . Did you do what i asked to . If yes then you should be seeing something getting printedn in the console tab of the browser dev tools . If you see something can you tell me how it looks like ?

Comment: crypto.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: action.assetList is not iterable
    at crypto (crypto.js:10)
    at combination (redux.js:528)
    at dispatch (redux.js:288)
    at index.js:11
    at dispatch (redux.js:659)
    at index.js:70
There are lots of errors but this one is the one relevant with the issue @Shyam

Comment: @Ayo add `console.log(action.assetList)` below this `case UPDATE_ASSET_LIST:` in your crypto.js file as told by @Shyam and remember to comment out `return [ ...action.assetList, ];` this line. Then show what output you get.